# How to save old state values react

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, state, react-functional-component

I want to not loose my other states, when changing one in functional component. I know how to do it in class components, but how you do it in functional? Class component `this.setState({...this.state, somestate: somestate});`

My Functional component looks like this now:

```
const [product, setProduct] = useState({});
  let { id } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    let productFromLocalStorage = localStorage[id];
    setProduct(JSON.parse(productFromLocalStorage));
  }, [id]);

function handleName(event) {
    setProduct({name: event.target.value});
    // setName(event.target.value);
  }

return (
    <div style={styles.container}>
      <h1 style={styles.title}>Product {product.name} Edit Page</h1>
      <form style={styles.form} onSubmit={handleSave}>
        <label style={styles.label}>
          Name: <input value={product.name} type="text" onChange={handleName}></input>
        </label>
        <label style={styles.label}>
          EAN: <input value={product.ean} type="text" onChange={handleEan}></input>
        </label>
        <label style={styles.label}>
          Type: <input value={product.type} type="text" onChange={handleType}></input>
        </label>
        <label style={styles.label}>
          Weight:{' '}
          <input value={product.weight} type="text" onChange={handleWeight}></input>
        </label>
        <label style={styles.label}>
          Color:{' '}
          <input value={product.color} type="text" onChange={handleColor}></input>
        </label>
        <label style={styles.label}>
          Active:{' '}
          <input value={product.active} type="checkbox" onChange={handleActive}></input>
        </label>

        <input style={styles.submitButton} type="submit" value="SAVE"></input>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
function handleSave(event) {
    const productInfo = {
      name: product.name,
      ean: product.ean,
      type: product.type,
      weight: product.weight,
      color: product.color,
      active: product.active,
    };
    localStorage.setItem(id, JSON.stringify(productInfo));
    alert('Product: ' + name + ' edited!');
  }
```

my product state has other params like weight and etc... when I am setting setProduct({name: event.target.value}); other values gets empty. How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are doing is overriding so like you said you need to keep current values so do this:

`setProduct({...product, name: event.target.value})`

Comment: @Emilis sorry to push but can you accept it now, it helps me out! thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same via useState() also,

```
const [product, setProduct] = useState({});
someHandler=(event)=>(
setProduct(product=>{
...product,
name:event.target.value
});
)
```